# special characters and compose key in Kile

Tags: accents, ubuntu, kile, keyboard

I've been using Kile (with various Ubuntu distributions) for ages without any problem to write my maths papers. Now, for some reason I was recently forced to upgrade my system to Ubuntu 20.04, and this created a new annoying problem in Kile 2.9.93:

**Context**:
I often have to use special characters, typically French accents such as *à,è,è,î* etc. Since I'm using a US keyboard layout on my laptop I'm efficiently and successfully using the KDE "compose key" feature to type those throughout my whole operating system: inputting `Alt+'+e` results in *é*, `Alt+"+i` results in *ï* and so on... I want Kile to automatically substitute these (virtually, indirectly inputted) special characters by their LaTex equivalent. This was working fine untill now.

**Problem**:
Since the last upgrade this doesn't work anymore. What is really weird is that if I disable the "substitute special characters" in Kile and input any of my compose-key combinations (say, `Alt+'+e`) then Kile **does** recognize the input and correctly displays é in the editor. So this bug appears to be caused by the interaction of the "substitute special characters" Kile feature with the "compose key" KDE option.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? And does anyone have any solution? Of course I can always manually input the LaTex command `\'e` for *é* and so on, but after 15 years of practice I doubt that my muscle memory would be too happy. Also, what a waste of time!

Comment: Why even substitute? LaTeX has been able to handle utf8 chars like this for many years now

Comment: Yes of course that is a fair point, but this is tedious when collaborating with other people, typically old generations of mathematicians have not update anything since 1999 and their computers don't recognize UTF8 chars.

Comment: In my opinion, that is their problem, they need to step up, not drag the rest of us down

Comment: I kind of agree, but that's not really something I can say to my senior colleagues' faces, unfortunately

Comment: Sure, I would probably post process then. My senior collegues knew that if they wanted my help with something LaTeX related, then they had to use a modern latex installation and a modern editor, otherwise no help